# Change variable in selected class in C# without using wrappers, delegates

Tags: c#, pointers, delegates, console, wrapper

I'm programming my console and I want to have one console action for variables. User should create new ConsoleVariableAction and past variable he wants to assign to it. I need to be able to access this variable from the ConsoleVariableAction class.

I tried a lot of different ways. First I tried to create wrapper.

```
public class ConsoleVariableCommand<T> : ConsoleCommand where T : Wrapper 
{
    protected Wrapper wrapper;

    public ConsoleVariableCommand(T wrapper)
    {
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public override void Perform (List<string> args)
    {
        if (args.Count > 1)
            wrapper = Utils.FromString<T> (args [1]);
    }

}
```

It was annoying, because when I wanted to past in int I must create IntWrapper first. Second option was to past function with delegate. However even this was annoying. You must write method for every variable you want to have in the console.

```
public class ConsoleVariableCommand
{
    public delegate void Set(string val);
    protected Set setter;

    public ConsoleVariableCommand(Set setter)
    {
        this.setter = setter;
    }

    public override void Perform (List<string> args)
    {
        if (args.Count > 1)
            setter (args [1]);
    }

}
```

Then I tried pointers too, but it's not working.

```
public class ConsoleVariableCommand<T> : ConsoleCommand
{
    protected unsafe T variable;

    public unsafe ConsoleVariableCommand (T variable)
    {
        this.variable = &variable;
    }

    public override void Perform (List<string> args)
    {
        if (variable != null && args.Count > 1) 
        {
            variable = Utils.FromString<T>(args[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

So is there a way how to do this without wrappers, delegates or pointers?

Comment: Would keeping the variables in a single dictionary, instead of having individual variables, work in your scenario?